# iPhone SQLite3 problem - "No such column"

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

When I run the following query in an iPhone app

```
@"select name, identifier, score, delta from startups order by name ASC"
```

I get the following error in my logs:

```
sqlite error: no such column: score
```

However, running pragma table_info(startups) in my sqlite3 database yields the following:

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(startups);
0|id|INTEGER|0||1
1|name|TEXT|0||0
2|identifier|TEXT|0||0
3|score|DOUBLE|0|'0'|0
4|delta|DOUBLE|0|'0'|0
5|cached|INTEGER|0|'0'|0
```

I've run clean and build several times, triple-checked the db, and cannot figure out why this error is appearing. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks, StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind - problem was that the iPhone simulator was caching the sqlite3 database. Clean and build did not remove this cached sqlite3 version. Had to manually go in and rm -rf the app directory under

/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications

Then it got rebuilt, the database was re-copied, and everything was hunky-dory.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved me from hours of struggle!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding 'score' with square brackets? (in case it's a reserved word):

```
@"select name, identifier, [score], delta from startups order by name ASC"
```